# How to Backup of all store data in database and saved files in folder using laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

> I am working on a Laravel project. As per requirement i want to make a backup
>   of 
>       all user posts. 
>       Like image and video with date. Please suggest how i can do this.
>       I have searched there is some packages for sql backup . How i can take 
>       backup of all files?

Comment: That depends on how your images are stored. If they're in `storage/app`, just zip that folder up. https://github.com/spatie/laravel-backup can probably help.

Comment: Create a cron that will run in the background and for every new image or video entry the cron will create a copy in some other directory.